# Unexpected behavior in eval in php < 7.4

Tags: php, eval, behavior

The following code:

```
<?php

function e($m, $n) {
    return eval(
        'return new class() {

            // '. str_repeat('a', $m). '
            public function test() {
                return "'. $n. '";
            }

        };'
    );
}

for ($i = 131; $i < 140; $i++) {
    printf("%d: %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n",
        $i,
        e($i, 1)->test(),
        e($i, 2)->test(),
        e($i, 1)->test(),
        e($i, 2)->test(),
        e($i + 1, 1)->test(),
        e($i + 1, 2)->test()
    );
}
```

When run using php 7.4 or 8.* it prints

```
131: 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2
132: 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2
133: 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2
134: 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2
135: 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2
136: 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2
137: 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2
138: 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2
139: 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2
```

which is expected. When run using php 7.3 - 7.0 it prints

```
131: 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1
132: 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2
133: 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2
134: 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2
135: 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1
136: 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
137: 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
138: 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
139: 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

which is quite unexpected. I haven't found a workaround and I really need one!

Initially it seemed to be about the number of characters in the beginning of the eval'd code that are the same, but when the code is more complex this is no longer the case.

Please, help!

Comment: Why do you need a comment in a temporary function? Does the problem go away if you get rid of that?

Comment: The comment is just to get some characters that are the same in the beginning of the eval'd code. A similar result can be achieved by changing the method name.

Comment: Why are you using eval ? You should avoid it.

Comment: I know but I assure you that I have a valid use case!

Comment: That's definitely a bug, and another illustrative case would be to call it as `e($i, $i)`. You can try filing the bug at https://bugs.php.net and hope for a workaround, but ultimately PHP7 is EOL, a fix is unlikely beyond "use 8", and you're never going to get away from people suggesting not using `eval()` at all, which I would also suggest.

Comment: @Sammitch I don't think anyone will address the issue at bugs.php.net. And about using eval - my use case is similar to that of jmespath and my only viable option other than using eval is their approach - using files. (https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.php/blob/master/src/CompilerRuntime.php)

Answer (score 2):

While I have no concrete idea what is causing this bug, my gut says that it's something to do with the object reference being returned from the eval'd code.

That said, while I was fiddling around with test cases it started working for some reason with the following code:

```php
for ($i = 0; $i < 1024; $i++) {
    
    $result = [];
    $status = false;
    for( $k=0; $k<6; ++$k) {
        $r = e($i, $i)->test();
        $result[] = $r;
        if( $r != $i ) {
            $status = true;
        }
    }
    
    if( $status ) {
        printf("%3d: %3d, %3d, %3d, %3d, %3d, %3d\n",
            $i,
            ...$result
        );
    }
}
```

If anything it's probably the array assignment, or merely having another actual operation between invocations of `eval()` code, or having an opportunity to GC the orphan eval object result and avoid pollution.

Questionable if it will actually work in your actual code, but it's something. You should still also file that bug.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it in the morning.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what cause your problem, but usage of `eval()` must be avoided when it's possible, and here it's possible:

```
<?php

class MyTestClass {
    private $n;
    private $m;

    public function __construct($m, $n) {
        $this->m = str_repeat('a', $m);
        $this->n = $n;
    }

    public function test() {
        return $this->n;
    }
}

function evalClass($m, $n) {
    return new MyTestClass($m, $n);
}

for ($i = 131; $i < 140; $i++) {
    echo $i. ': '. evalClass($i, 1)->test(). ', '. evalClass($i, 2)->test(). ', '. evalClass($i, 1)->test(). ', '. evalClass($i, 2)->test(). ', '. evalClass($i + 1, 1)->test(). ', '. evalClass($i + 1, 2)->test(). "\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
131: 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2
132: 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2
133: 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2
134: 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2
135: 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2
136: 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2
137: 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2
138: 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2
139: 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2
```

Comment: The code that I actually eval is quite complex and the best version without eval is many times slower. In the question I provided the minimal code that demonstrates the problem.